# Kinect Motion Tracking - Displaying Wrist Coordinates

Tags: c#, position, kinect

I'm trying to play around with the KinectExplorer sample in the SDKs and having an issue.

My goal is to have a textBox presented in the KinectWindow that shows in real-time the X,Y,Z coordinates of the left hand wrist.

All the skeleton drawing is done in a file called KinectSkeleton.cs but I can not control the text that appears in the KinectWindow through it.

Any suggestions on how to get that to work?

Comment: First welcome to stackoverflow. There should be some clarifications. Are you ok with retrieving left wrist data. And what is this KinectWindow you keep talking about.

Comment: @ShamithaSilva Thank you, and sorry for the late answer. Let me explain: There is an SDK sample called KinectExplorer. If you run it in Visual Studio, 2 windows will open up: 1 is a window telling you whether a Kinect device is plugged in or not, and the 2nd window is a window named "KinectWindow" that has the depth video, audio controls, regular video, skeleton and other options in it. Now, what I want is to have real-time x,y,z coordinates of the left hand wrist in a textBox in either a completely new window or in that "KinectWindow". New window would even work better for me.

Comment: @ShamithaSilva I need to continue in a new comment. All the skeleton drawing functions are in a file called KinectSkeleton.cs which has not associated window to it. I would like to have another window open up, place textBoxes in it and control the information appearing in those textBoxes through that KinectSkeleton file preferably. Thank you again :)